# get the 240x670 in a string and delete?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I want to delete part of it:

```
string_string_string_240x670.bmp
string_string_string_550x450.bmp
string_string_string_250x950.bmp
```

I want to remove the number part `240x670`.bmp

will become:

```
string_string_string_.bmp
string_string_string_.bmp
string_string_string_.bmp
```

I tried:

```
$a = preg_replace('[0-9]x[0-9]', '', $a);
```

but no success.

Comment: Do you always have `bmp` extension at the end?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah! just want to remove the 232x323

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/mB6sK9/1

Comment: You have some issues in your code. Most important forgetting about delimiters: `preg_replace('/[0-9]+x[0-9]+(\.\w+)$/', '$1', $a);`

Comment: Your attempt is good! You are just missing a few things: 1) You need delimiters around your regex, e.g. `/<regex here>/` or use `~`, or `#` instead of the slashes. 2) Quantifiers, yes, right now you just match 1 digit. So to match multiple digits you need to use `+` the quantifier for 1 or more matches, e.g. `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that PHP regexes use [*regex delimiters*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), and your regex is actually parse as `0-9]x[0-9` since the paired outer `[...]` are treated as delimiters. Use the common `/.../` or `~...~` to delimit the patterns.

Since you say the files always have `bmp` extension, I was going to suggest

```
'~_[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.bmp$~'
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB6sK9/1)

**Details**:

- `_`  - an underscore
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `x` - an `x`
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `bmp` - a literal string `bmp`
- `$` - end of string.

*If the extension can be any*, you may also leverage `pathinfo` to split the path and only work on the filename:

```
$s = "string_string_string_240x670.bmp";
$p = pathinfo($s);
if (isset($p["filename"])) {
    echo preg_replace('~_\d+x\d+$~', '_.', $p["filename"]) . $p["extension"];
}
```

Here, the `_\d+x\d+$` does not care what extension you have, it just replaces the last `_`+`digits`+`x`+`digits` at the end of the string (filename).

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/1u1iiG)

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
$a = preg_replace('/\d+x\d+/', '', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/\d+x\d+/g` will work for you.

```
$re = "/\\d+x\\d+/"; 
$str = "string_string_string_240x670.bmp\nstring_string_string_550x450.bmp\nstring_string_string_250x950.bmp"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Result will be:

```
string_string_string_.bmp
string_string_string_.bmp
string_string_string_.bmp
```

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/oG6yL3/3)

Comment: I think you are duplicating @horcrux answer.